# Loop optimization issues in node.js and chrome?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, google-chrome, v8

I happened to see the saying that avoiding to read the length attribute of an array at every iteration saves execution time.
But I don't think it matters and made an experiment.
Then I met the questions.
Here's the code.

```
// Function to get the execution time.
function testFunction (func) {
    console.time(func.name)
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        func()
    }
    console.timeEnd(func.name)
}

// Init the array to iterate.
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    arr.push(0)
}

function loopWithSavedLength () {
    let len = arr.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = i
    }
}

function loopWithoutSavedLength() {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i
    }
}

testFunction(loopWithoutSavedLength)
testFunction(loopWithSavedLength)
```

And the output is very strange:

```
loopWithoutSavedLength: 889.633ms
loopWithSavedLength: 1023.269ms
```

I tried many times under Node.js 9.8.0(with v8 6.2.414.46-node.21) and the loopWithoutSavedLength execution time is always shorter than loopWithSavedLength's.

I execute the same script in chrome 66.0.3359.181(with v8 6.6.346.32) console and they are barely the same.

```
loopWithoutSavedLength: 1475.060302734375ms
loopWithSavedLength: 1493.14892578125ms
```

Then I thought it might be issue with assignment and test empty loop.
Here is new code.

```
function assignmentLoopWithSavedLength () {
    let len = arr.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = i
    }
}

function assignmentLoopWithoutSavedLength () {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = i
    }
}

function emptyLoopWithSavedLength () {
    let len = arr.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {}
}

function emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength () {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {}
}


testFunction(emptyLoopWithSavedLength)
testFunction(emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength)
testFunction(assignmentLoopWithSavedLength)
testFunction(assignmentLoopWithoutSavedLength)
```

The results in node.js:

```
emptyLoopWithSavedLength: 580.978ms
emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength: 584.923ms
assignmentLoopWithSavedLength: 1046.899ms
assignmentLoopWithoutSavedLength: 901.542ms
```

The results in chrome console:

```
emptyLoopWithSavedLength: 584.126953125ms
emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength: 892.776123046875ms
assignmentLoopWithSavedLength: 1455.418212890625ms
assignmentLoopWithoutSavedLength: 1449.7529296875ms
```

Later I realized the value stored in arr may influence the consequence and it does.

New code here:

```
let arr = []
function initArr () {
    arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        arr.push(0)
    }
}

function testFunction (func) {
    initArr()
    console.time(func.name)
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        func()
    }
    console.timeEnd(func.name)
}
```

The result in node.js:

```
emptyLoopWithSavedLength: 560.739ms
emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength: 1134.274ms
assignmentLoopWithSavedLength: 1841.544ms
assignmentLoopWithoutSavedLength: 1609.649ms
```

The result in chrome console:

```
emptyLoopWithSavedLength: 592.8720703125ms
emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength: 910.886962890625ms
assignmentLoopWithSavedLength: 1457.467041015625ms
assignmentLoopWithoutSavedLength: 1488.855224609375ms
```

Now new question comes up.

In conclusion:
1. In node.js, why is loopWithoutSavedLength time always smaller than loopWithSavedLength no matter array's elements are initialized to 0 or not?
2. Why does creating new array and initializing its elements to 0 make a different consequence?

Comment: JS interpreters have now optimized `for` loops automatically so you don't have to manually optimize them.

Comment: @jfriend00 I am not trying to manually optimize `for` loops but only exactly wondering the mechanism of automatic optimization:)

Comment: Saving the length property to a separate variable is a manual optimization.  That's what I was referring to.

Comment: FYI, a pre-filled array is already allocated in memory so there is no array allocation time spent inside the timed loop.  Doing a `.push()` inside the loop has to resize the array every iteration of the loop (which takes time).

Comment: @jfriend00 But the initialization is not inside the timer (´･_･`)

Comment: I don't understand what your last comment means.  Preallocating and prefilling an array outside the timer is going to be faster than growing the array inside the timer because growing the array over and over in each array iteration takes times.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry for my poor English. I mean I put the initArr() invocation before the timer starts in testFunction(). Will the allocation time still influce the timer in this case?

Comment: I do not think so.  The array is already fully allocated so there is no need to reallocate it when just assigning to its elements.  I does make a difference whether you pre-fill the array or not.  If you just allocate the length, but don't prefill, some interpreters will treat that as a sparse array and not allocated space for its elements until you actually assign to them.  But, if you pre-fill the array, then it is fully allocated before the loop.

Comment: @jfriend00 I figure out what you mean finally. I thought you were talking about my mistakes in the experiment :D. Thanks for your explaination of VLA in js.

Comment: Notice that in your second test run, you wrote `testFunction(emptyLoopWithSavedLength)` instead of `testFunction(emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength)`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for reminding. So saving the length does improve the  performance in chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V8 developer here.

Question 1: loopWithoutSavedLength is faster because accessing an element needs to perform a bounds check, which needs to load the length anyway. It can be eliminated if the loop's condition already contains the same check. It is much harder for the compiler to eliminate the additional check if you save the length. So in effect, saving the length manually means that work is duplicated. That said, the difference is usually too small to matter (or even be measurable). See the excellent writeup at https://mrale.ph/blog/2014/12/24/array-length-caching.html for more details.

Question 2: I'm not sure. The values of the elements shouldn't matter; and in Chrome they don't. V8 in Node.js acts the same and should perform the same as in Chrome; but maybe there's a difference between the two V8 versions you've tested. I'm confused by the results you got for `emptyLoopWithoutSavedLength` in Node.js, which apparently went from 584 to 1134 for no good reason at all -- maybe something else in your system caused a temporary slowdown? Can you reproduce this result?

Speaking of reproducing: when I run these tests repeatedly, I see performance differences of about 10% between repeated runs of the very same test (e.g. the results I got for `assignmentLoopWithSavedLength` over the course of 10 runs were between 1075 and 1222). That's not unusual; modern computers are complex machines with many layers and many sources of performance variations. It just means that when you do a single run of two tests, and you see 1400 and 1450 milliseconds, that might not mean anything -- next time around they might swap results. If you see 1455 and 1449, the difference is almost certainly noise.

Comment: I can reproduce the result for every time. But it seems not to be issues with elements in array. If I move `initArr()` out of `testFunction()` and invoke it directly in the top level at the script beginning, the result is almost the same(slower than previous tests). I think the new reference for the variable `arr` in `initArr()` may be relevant to the result. If I keep the reference unchanged and use assignment rather than `push()` inside `initArr()`, the execution time is close to the previous tests. Is it because top-level objects are cached to have a faster access or some other magic?

Comment: Yes, there are special optimizations for global variables that are only assigned once; specifically optimized code can inline the value rather than reloading it every time. So the additional `arr = []` assignments (even just one!) probably end up making the `arr` accesses (as opposed to the `arr[i]` element accesses) slower.